# Run loop outside websocket server

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make a little proyect where the user ask for some data to the server and then the server return an array of random numbers.

I need to be changing the array all the time, so I put the code inside a while loop. Now I want the loop and the server running at the same time, and when a user asks for the array, send a "copy" of the array at the time of requesting it.

This is what I've tried:

```
import asyncio, websockets, json, numpy as np, multiprocessing as mp

result = []

def server():
    print('Server running')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websockets.serve(echo, 'localhost', 8765))
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

async def echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        msg_in = json.loads(message) # Converts JSON string to dictionary.
        if msg_in['instr']=="request_data":
            print(result)
            msg_out={'data': str(result)}
            await websocket.send(msg_out['data'])

def randomLoop():
    print('Loop running')
    while True:
        result_array = np.rint(100*np.random.rand(3))
        result = result_array.tolist()

serverThread = mp.Process(target=server)
loopThread = mp.Process(target=randomLoop)

serverThread.start()
loopThread.start()

serverThread.join()
loopThread.join()
```

And this is the code that I had before (whithout the loop):

```
import asyncio, websockets, json

result = [1,2,3]

async def echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        msg_in = json.loads(message) # Converts JSON string to dictionary.
        if msg_in['instr']=="request_data":
            print(result)
            msg_out={'data': str(result)}
            await websocket.send(msg_out['data'])


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websockets.serve(echo, 'localhost', 8765))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The code before the while loop, was working perfectly, now I don't know what to do. I also don't know how multiprocessing works, I was just trying.

Comment: What problem are you having? Are you getting an error?

Comment: The loop is not running, is not even printing "Loop Running" or "Server running"